# Oracle Invalid Identifier (with Inner Join)

Tags: oracle

I'm having an "Invalid Identifier" in Oracle because of the "B.username" (username column does exist in USER table). When i remove this, it's working fine. How to resolve this issue? I came from a MySQL background.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT qNA.assignment, qNA.regDate, B.username, (
    SELECT DISTINCT NVL(idx, 0) 
    FROM EK_USERGRADE
    WHERE year = (SELECT DISTINCT userGradeNo FROM EK_USER WHERE ID = qNA.userIdx)
) AS userGradeIdx
FROM EK_NEWTESTAPPLICANT qNA
WHERE IDX = :idx ) A 
INNER JOIN EK_USER  B ON (A.userIdx = B.ID)
```

Comment: You have a table called `USER`? its a reserved row in oracle

Comment: It would be better if you could describe the tables.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the table name. The query is working when i get rid the B.username. The username is called/pulled in EK_USER table.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this with a simplified version of your query:

```
-- test tables
create table NEWTESTAPPLICANT as select 1 useridx from dual  ;
create table B as select 1 id, 'name1' username from dual ;

-- query
select *
from (
  select B.username
  from NEWTESTAPPLICANT qNA
) A join B on A.useridx = B.id ;
-- ORA-00904: "B"."USERNAME": invalid identifier
```

There's no "username" column in the NEWTESTAPPLICANT table, which causes the error.  A LATERAL inline view (examples see [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1)) may do the trick ...

```
-- query
select 
  *
from B, lateral (
  select B.username
  from NEWTESTAPPLICANT qNA
) A ;

-- result
ID  USERNAME  USERNAME  
1   name1     name1
```

This works with Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that both your virtual table A and users B have the same column name "username". Specify alias in the main select, like "Select A.* , B.* from(...".

Comment: My bad, the specified cause is not the issue. The issue is, that table A cant find the tables B columns, cause of the syntax problem . Why you need username in table A, when you can still access it from B in your main select?

Comment: No, the EK_USER only have the username

Comment: The question is, why you include B.username in the formation of table A, when you can still access it from the inner join with B. Its an overkill. I would understand the need, if you used outer join, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ORA-00903?

*User* is a reserved word are you sure you created this table? Table name cannot be a reserved word.